# Finding comma separated values with a colon delimiter

Tags: php, mysql

I am setting values in my database for tourneyID,Selected,Paid,Entered,date then separating each selection with a colon

So I have a string that may look like this

```
    187,S,,,09-21-2013:141,S,,,06-21-2013:144,S,,,05-24-2013
```

but it also could look like this

```
    145,S,,,07-12-2013:142,S,,,05-24-2013:187,S,,,09-21-2013
```

and some times is looks like this

```
    87,S,,,07-11-2013:125,S,,,06-14-2013
```

I am trying to find this sequence: `187,S,,,09-21-2013`

I have data stored like that because I paid a programmer to code it for me. Now, as I learn, I see it was not the best solution, but it is what I have till I learn more and it is working.

My problem is when using LIKE it returns both the 187 and 87 values

```
    $getTeams = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM teams 
    WHERE (team_tourney_vector LIKE '%$tid,S,P,,$tourney_start_date%' 
    OR team_tourney_vector LIKE '%$tid,S,,,$tourney_start_date%') 
    AND division='$division'");
```

I tried this using `FIND_IN_SET()` 
but it would only return the the team id for this string

```
187,S,,,09-21-2013:141,S,,,06-21-2013:144,S,,,05-24-2013
```

and does not find the team id for this string

```
145,S,,,07-12-2013:142,S,,,05-24-2013:187,S,,,09-21-2013

   SELECT * FROM teams WHERE FIND_IN_SET('187',team_tourney_vector) AND (team_tourney_vector LIKE '%S,,,09-21-2013%')
```

Any thoughts on how to achieve this?

Comment: Why, oh why, do you have data stored like that?

Comment: Do you have the ability/access to change the schema?

Comment: @lc I have data stored like that because I paid a (programer) to code it for me. Now, as I learn, I see it was not the best solution, but it is what I have till I learn more and it is working. I do see the disadvantage like updating has to be done with 2 different screens. I got no help from the guy who helped me other than to say he needed more money to fix his problem. So I rolled up my sleeves and coded a patch myself. Just like the solution I came up with to fix this bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution to the problem above using RLIKE

```
    $tourney_start_date=date('m-d-Y', strtotime($tourney_start_date));
    $vector = '"'.$tid.',S,,,'.$tourney_start_date.'"';
    $getTeams = mysql_query("
    SELECT * FROM `teams` 
    WHERE `team_tourney_vector` 
    RLIKE $vector 
    AND division='$division'");
```

Comment: Still doesn't prevent false matches.  Backslashes before commas are not needed.  Nonstandard double-quote characters used for SQL string literals.

Comment: removed the backslashed but don't understand your comment about nonstandard double quotes, when removing them it created an error

Comment: SQL uses single-quotes for string literals and date literals.  MySQL non-standardly also uses double-quotes in the same way, but the ANSI/ISO SQL standard (and most other brands of RDBMS) use double-quotes to delimite column names and table names.  You should get into the habit of using quotes in the standard way, in case you use another brand of database someday.

Comment: Thanks Bill, I do want to do it correctly, I will read up and make the change

Comment: I finally figured out how to make this better with your suggestion Bill. Tables just work better, less to go wrong

`SELECT * 
FROM  team_tourneys
INNER JOIN tourneys
ON team_tourneys.tid =tourneys.tid
WHERE  team_id = '$team_id'`

Answer (score 2):

You are making this task far more difficult by storing the data in the format you're using.

You need to store tourney vectors in a separate table.  Each tourney goes in a separate row, and each comma-separated field goes in a separate column.

Then you can use SQL to look up specific matching $tid rows, and you can even use indexes to help speed up those searches.

Also, MySQL dates should be stored in YYYY-MM-DD format.

Also see my answer to [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-comma-separated-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574#3653574)

Comment: dates are stored in YYYY-MM-DD then flipped to a human version using date('m-d-Y', strtotime($tourney_start_date)); Thanks for the tip on your method of storing a comma separated list :)

Comment: Don't know what you mean, because your example clearly shows dates stored in MM-DD-YYYY format.

Comment: Ahhh I see what you mean, I store it YYYY-MM-DD originally then switch to m-d-y and store that. I get it

Answer (score 0):

Don't use sql. It is much easier to use PHP `strpos`

```
$getTeams = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM teams WHERE division='$division'");

while ( $rows = mysql_fetch_array($getTeams) ) {
  if ( strpos($rows['team_tourney_vector'],'187,S,,,09-21-2013') ) {
    echo $rows['team_tourney_vector'];
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried your example as seen below, but for every id in the db it returns Warning: strpos() [function.strpos]: Empty delimiter in /home/premier/public_html/tournament_teams1.php on line 69
not found

Comment: $getTeams = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM teams WHERE division='$division'");
while ( $rows = mysql_fetch_array($getTeams) ) {
$id = $rows['ID'];
$TeamName = $rows['TeamName'];
$ManagerFirstName = $rows['ManagerFirstName'];
$ManagerLastName = $rows['ManagerLastName'];
$team_tourney_vector = $rows['team_tourney_vector'];     
  if ( strpos('187,S,,,09-21-2013',$rows['team_tourney_vector']) ) {
echo $team_tourney_vector; } else { echo 'not found';}}

Comment: If you do this, you might as well store your data in a text file.

Comment: Sorry, I always do that with strpos. Mix haystack and needle. Updated and should work now